# Combiner without Reducer in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can I write a Hadoop code that has only Mappers and Combiners (i.e. mini-reducers with no reducer)?

> job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
> job.setCombinerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
>
> conf.setInt("mapred.reduce.tasks", 0);

I was trying to do so but I always see that I have one reduce task on the job tracker link

> Launched reduce tasks = 1

How can I delete reducers while keeping combiners? is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you describe you should use Reducers. Use as key: Context.getInputSplit().getPath() + Context.getInputSplit().getStart() - this combination is unique for each Mapper.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, that can definitely solve my problem :)

Comment: Would you not be better off using a custom partitioner (say, the identity) and using the host name as key?  That should make the shuffle trivial, which is faster than the full shuffle that arises from @Evgeny's clever trick

Comment: Yeah that should also work :) but What do you mean by "full shuffle"?

Comment: I tried to answer how output of every Mapper can be processed by another Reducer. But, indeed, as algorithm, the requirements are questionable: if output of every Mapper is processed by another Reducer then why Reducer is needed in the first place? Thus, probably there is no need for shuffle, sort and reduce at all?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I just saw your answer. You'are right, for my case, each mapper has its independent tasks and thus I wanted a mini-reducer that will loop over all the data generated by a mapper X to start. Anyway, I solved the problem using the in-mapper combiners :-) in this case no shuffle will be used/consumed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your job that you don't care about the reducer: [JobConf.html#setNumReduceTasks(int)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setNumReduceTasks%28int%29)

```
// new Hadoop API
jobConf.setNumReduceTasks(0);

// old Hadoop API
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

You can achieve the something with [IdentityReducer](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityReducer.html).

> Performs no reduction, writing all input values directly to the output.

I'm not sure whether you can keep combiners but I will start with the previous lines.

Comment: I tried this option (i.e. job.setNumReduceTasks(0); )
This option sets the number of reduce tasks to Zero, but we can not have combiners in this case !!!

Comment: @HadoopUser Then use a reducer! :) Why you don't want to use a reducer?

Comment: In the beginning, I wanted all the map tasks that were handeled by a mapper X to be executed by the same reducer, the problem is that I don't know what to choose as a key to guarantee that. So, I said having a combiner will make this task easier as it doesn't take a look at the key .. It just takes into account all the map tasks executed by a Mapper X as a package.